# using declval with reference types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to understand how the assignment of `int &` to `double` below in conjunction with `declval` works? Is `T` deduced to something other than `int &` ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename U, typename = void>
struct assignment : std::false_type{};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct assignment<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>())>> : std::true_type {}; 
 

int main() {
    // int &x = 23.4; // does not compile since x is not a const ref
    static_assert(assignment<int &, double>::value);  // why is this OK?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is T deduced to something other than `int &` ?

T will *still* be deduced as `int&`, so `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` will be roughly equivalent to

```
int& f();
double&& g();

f() = g(); // assignment
```

Note that `f() = g()` is still well-formed because `f()` returns a reference to an already created `int` that can be *assigned* to a `double`. But if you do `int& f() { return 23.4; }`, then you will get a compile error because non-`const` lvalue references cannot be *initialized* by a rvalue. Instead, you can create a helper function which take `T` as its parameter type

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename = void>
struct initialize : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
void accepted(T);

template <typename T, typename U>
struct initialize<T, U, 
  std::void_t<decltype(accepted<T>(std::declval<U>()))>> : std::true_type {};
```

This will make `static_assert(initialize<int &, double>::value)` fail because `int&` cannot be rvalue-initialized.

Comment: I'm still confused why ```double d = 3.3; int &i = d;``` does not compile while ```f() = g();``` above does?

Comment: @user3882729  `int &i = d` is initialization. `f() = g()` is not initialization, it is assignment, which means that the `int&` returned by `f()` has already been successfully initialized. Try to imagine `f()` returning an lvalue reference to a global `int` variable, then `f() = 0.0` is still well-formed.

Comment: Thanks, I'd assumed thus far that with references, initialization is the same as assignment as they can't be re-seated. Above is an interesting counter example.

Comment: @user3882729 : When you initialize a reference variable, you're saying which object it aliases; when you assign to a reference variable, you are actually assigning to said aliased object. So really, they could not be more different.